# How to create kotlin login with sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin, android-sqlite

how can I create a login in koltin using sqlite.

User register

```
 bt_204.setOnClickListener {
            val admin = AdminSQliteOpenHelper(this, "administracion",null,1)
            val bd = admin.writableDatabase
            val registro = ContentValues()
            registro.put("nombre_usuario", et_nombre_201.text.toString())
            registro.put("clave1", et_pasword_204.text.toString())
            registro.put("clave2",et_paword_203.text.toString() )
            bd.insert("usuario", null , registro)
            bd.close()
            et_nombre_201.setText("")
            et_paword_203.setText("")
            et_pasword_204.setText("")
            Toast.makeText(this,"Usuarios registrado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent (this,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

main activity

try this but the app is destroyed(I am a beginner)

```
   bt_ingresar_04.setOnClickListener {
            val admin = AdminSQliteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 1)
            val bd = admin.writableDatabase
            val fila = bd.rawQuery(
                "select nombre_usuario,clave1 from usuario where nombre_usuario=${et_02.text} &&    ${etp_03.text}"
                null
            )
            if (fila.moveToFirst()) {
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity_03::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Usuario no registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is `etp_03.text`?

Comment: et_02 = username
etp_03 = password

Comment: So the column nombre_usuario stores the username. Which column stores the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` is the logical operator for Java but not for sql. You must use `AND`.

Also in the `where` clause of the query you must specify all the needed column names, but you don't. You specify only the column `nombre_usuario`.

Also the parameters `et_02.text` and `etp_03.text` should be properly quoted, so the final result is something like:

```
where column1 = 'value1' and column2 = 'value2'
```

But the proper way of doing this is by using `?` placholders and pass the parameters in the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()` as an array of strings.

So change to this:

```
val fila = bd.rawQuery(
    "select nombre_usuario, clave1 from usuario where nombre_usuario = ? and column_password = ?",
    arrayOf(et_02.text, etp_03.text)
)
```

Replace `column_password` with the name of the column where you store the password.

Also, in `bt_204.setOnClickListener`, in this line:

```
registro.put("clave2",et_paword_203.text.toString() )
```

maybe there is a typo for `et_paword_203`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have one last question, what function does this fulfill? and the arrayOf (et_02.text, etp_03.text).

Comment: The 2nd argument of rawQuery() is an array of strings and there you pass all the parameters of your query. So all `?` placeholders in the query will be replaced by the items of your query.